# Changing Screenshot Directory for mpv Media Player in Ubuntu 17.10

Tags: mpv-media-player

I'm using mpv Media Player in Ubuntu 17.10, and whenever I take a screenshot it goes to the home directory. Is there any way to change the directory for the screenshots taken?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Edit**: Based on [a comment by doug](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1000376/changing-screenshot-directory-for-mpv-media-player-in-ubuntu-17-10/1000403?noredirect=1#comment1617470_1000403), who does a lot of work with mpv, one can simply edit `~/.config/mpv.conf` to add `screenshot-directory=~/Public/` if `$HOME/Public` is the desired destination.

---

The following works with `mpv/xenial,now 2:0.28.0~xenial1 amd64 [installed]` and with `mpv/bionic,now 0.27.0-2ubuntu4 amd64 [installed]`. I haven't tested with the version available on 17.10.

I copied over `/usr/share/applications/mpv.desktop` to `$HOME/.local/share/applications`.

I then modified the `Exec` line from

```
Exec=mpv --player-operation-mode=pseudo-gui -- %U
```

to

```
Exec=mpv --player-operation-mode=pseudo-gui --screenshot-directory=$HOME/Public/ -- %U
```

and saved `SHOME/.local/share/applications/mpv.desktop`. Now, when I open a video with mpv and take a screenshot, the screenshot is saved to `$HOME/Public`.

Read https://mpv.io/manual/master/ for adjusting the quality of screenshots, naming them, and the format desired.

Comment: It worked perfectly after a small edit.

Comment: What was the edit? Maybe I can use it as well!

Comment: Well let's say I just wanted it in the Public directory, at first I copied your path: $HOME/Public/. But that created a $Home directory and a Public directory inside it. So instead I made the path into just: Public/

Comment: Thanks for that! I didn't see that but I'll recheck on my system.

Comment: Really the proper way is to just add an entry to `~/.config/mpv.conf`  So in your case the entry would be `screenshot-directory=Public/`  Note that options added to mpv.conf are not preceded by --

Comment: I tried that but it didn't work for me.

Comment: But `screenshot-directory=~/Public/` works.